# Plotting pairs where the 2nd element is a complex number

Tags: plotting, complex

How can I see the variation of 'y' for different values of 'x' using a plot in which 'y' are complex numbers ?

```
xValuesDb = 
  {6.*10^-6, 0.050006, 0.100006, 0.150006, 0.200006, 0.250006, 
   0.300006, 0.350006, 0.400006, 0.450006, 0.500006, 0.550006, 
   0.600006, 0.650006, 0.700006, 0.750006, 0.800006, 0.850006, 
   0.900006, 0.950006}

yValues = 
  {0.0499359 + 0.00218364 I, 0.0502323 + 0.00220999 I, 0.0505305 + 0.00223666 I, 
   0.0508304 + 0.00226367 I,  0.0511322 + 0.002291 I, 0.0514358 + 0.00231868 I, 
   0.0517412 + 0.00234669 I, 0.0520484 + 0.00237506 I,  0.0523575 + 0.00240377 I, 
   0.0526684 + 0.00243284 I,  0.0529812 + 0.00246227 I, 0.0532959 + 0.00249207 I, 
   0.0536125 + 0.00252223 I, 0.0539309 + 0.00255277 I, 0.0542513 + 0.00258369 I, 
   0.0545737 + 0.002615 I,  0.0548979 + 0.0026467 I, 0.0552242 + 0.00267879 I, 
   0.0555524 + 0.00271128 I, 0.0558826 + 0.00274418 I}

xyValuesAll = 
  MapThread[Riffle[{#1},{#2}]&, {xValuesDb, yValues}, 1] = 
    MapThread[Riffle[{#1},{#2}]&, {{xValuesDb, {131.263, yValues}},1]

ListPlot[xyValuesAll,
  AxesOrigin -> {λMin, 0},
  AxesLabel->{"BS density","Coverage Probability"}]
```

Comment: Your code cannot be executed because you have not provided an example of `{xValuesDb, yValues}`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: one possibility would be to have a 3DPlot with the z axis representing the imaginary part of y.

Answer (score 1):

```
xValuesDb = {6.*10^-6, 0.050006, 0.100006, 0.150006, 0.200006, 
   0.250006, 0.300006, 0.350006, 0.400006, 0.450006, 0.500006, 
   0.550006, 0.600006, 0.650006, 0.700006, 0.750006, 0.800006, 
   0.850006, 0.900006, 0.950006};

yValues = {0.0499359 + 0.00218364 I, 0.0502323 + 0.00220999 I, 
   0.0505305 + 0.00223666 I, 0.0508304 + 0.00226367 I, 
   0.0511322 + 0.002291 I, 0.0514358 + 0.00231868 I, 
   0.0517412 + 0.00234669 I, 0.0520484 + 0.00237506 I, 
   0.0523575 + 0.00240377 I, 0.0526684 + 0.00243284 I, 
   0.0529812 + 0.00246227 I, 0.0532959 + 0.00249207 I, 
   0.0536125 + 0.00252223 I, 0.0539309 + 0.00255277 I, 
   0.0542513 + 0.00258369 I, 0.0545737 + 0.002615 I, 
   0.0548979 + 0.0026467 I, 0.0552242 + 0.00267879 I, 
   0.0555524 + 0.00271128 I, 0.0558826 + 0.00274418 I};

xyValuesAllRe = Transpose[{xValuesDb, Re /@ yValues}];

xyValuesAllIm = Transpose[{xValuesDb, Im /@ yValues}];

xyValuesAllAbs = Transpose[{xValuesDb, Abs /@ yValues}];

ListPlot[
 {xyValuesAllRe, xyValuesAllIm, xyValuesAllAbs},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Green,
   Directive[Blue, AbsoluteDashing[{10, 10}]]},
 Joined -> True,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@
    {"BS density", 
     "Coverage Probability"}),
 PlotLegends -> {Re, Im, Abs}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way to do it is using a 3d plot. Just add this code to your definitions:

```
points = Table[{xValuesDb[[i]], Re@yValues[[i]], Im@yValues[[i]]}, {i,
Length@xValuesDb}]

ListPointPlot3D[points, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Re@Y", "Im@Y"}, 
PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: result]